# Integrate function returns vector instead of scalar

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, vector

When I try to integrate a function mapping a vector to a scalar Mathematica "ignores" the function and returns a vector independent of the function.

Here is a minimal example of my problem: I want to integrate the sum over all absolute values in a vector over a 2D unit circle. When I use the `Total` function for this, i.e. `f1` Mathematica returns a scalar (2.67) that looks reasonable. When I use my `f2` function which - as far as I know - should basically implement the `Total` function, it does not return a scalar but a vector `{0., 0.}`.

```
f1[x_] := Total[x]
f2[x_] := Apply[Plus, x]
NIntegrate[f1[Abs[x]], x \[Element] Ball[ConstantArray[0, 2]]]
NIntegrate[f2[Abs[x]], x \[Element] Ball[ConstantArray[0, 2]]]
```

When I directly compare what my `f2` function does it looks like it behaves like the `f1` function, i.e.
`f1[{0.2, 0.3 }] == f2[{0.2, 0.3}]` returns `True`.

I am puzzled by the (seemingly) different behavior of Mathematica depending on whether I use the `f2` function inside `NIntegrate` or outside; now I am looking for an explanation what happens here and how and why I have to modify the `f2` function such that it behaves like `f1` in my integral.

Comment: Can you report on the result of wrapping the `f1` integrand in an `Evaluate`? I have a feeling this is due to `NIntegrate` trying to transform the integrand before inserting values for `x` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, it's the first thing that popped in my mind as well, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Also writing the function explicitely does not seem to help either. I tried plotting the two side by side and they indeed both give what you would expect. It's kinda weird. Perhaps a bug?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Wrapping `f2` with `Evaluate` doesn't change the return value - it's still `{0., 0.}`.

Comment: Might have something to do with what `f2[Abs[x]]` evaluates to symbolically. Try `f2[x_?VectorQ] := Apply[Plus,x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sadly, that also doesn't change the output.

Comment: It did for me. Perhaps you didn't clear your first definition?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be because `f2[Abs[x]]` evaluates to `x` symbolically:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]; (* be sure to clear previous definitions *)
f1[x_] := Total[x]
f2[x_?VectorQ] := Apply[Plus, x]
NIntegrate[f1[Abs[x]], x \[Element] Ball[ConstantArray[0, 2]]]
NIntegrate[f2[Abs[x]], x \[Element] Ball[ConstantArray[0, 2]]]

(*
2.66667
2.66667
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why Mathematica doesn't recognize `x`to be a list!

Try

```
NIntegrate[f1[Abs[{x1, x2}]], {x1, x2} \[Element]Ball[ConstantArray[0, 2]]]
(*2.66667*)

NIntegrate[f2[Abs[{x1, x2}]], {x1, x2} \[Element]Ball[ConstantArray[0, 2]]]    
(*2.66667*)
```

Comment: That works! However, later on, I want to evaluate this on `n` dimensions which make it unfeasible to type in all `x_i` by hand. Any suggestion on how to solve this then?

Comment: @zimmerrol Sorry, no idea. I only know `(N)DSolve` is able to handle list-variables.

Comment: @zimmerrol The documentation states  that `Total[#]&`and `Apply[Plus,#]&`are equivalent, but simple test `Simplify[ Apply[Plus, x ] , x \[Element] Disk[] ] (*x*)`  shows it isn't!